# Error: Server Error (500) on Google App Engine site

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine returns "Error: Server Error" on one of my apps. I didn't change anything lately :) All I see in the log is a request for favicon.ico with "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.".

[System Status](https://code.google.com/status/appengine) for everybody is fine.

Any idea where to go from here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Engine - Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463916/google-app-engine-request-was-aborted-after-waiting-too-long-to-attempt-to-ser)

Comment: Thanks @SamueleMattiuzzo, interesting to keep an eye on! It seems to be running again now, was down for a few hours. It is a low traffic site indeed but called at least every hour to check on via uptime robot. I haven't had this error for all the years I have is running.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my python app. "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request. status 500". My app is not very low traffic app, it is receiving 2 request per seconds and most of them are failing